# Directive for Google Maps Market

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to create a directive for markers.

```
    angular.module("App").directive('marker', function () {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.6908333333, 9.14055555556),
        title: 'Marker'
      });

      marker.setMap(map.map);
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          map: '=map'
        },
        template: '{{marker}}'
     };
    });
```

I initialized Google Maps inside a controller.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
```

And HTML:

```
<marker map="map"></marker>
```

Map loads but marker doesn't.